# How can I compare a field of one model with a field in another model in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, report, odoo

I am using OpenEduCat for my institute on odoo 12.0 and 13.0. "Student Hall Ticket Report" is working fine if all the students have the same subjects in a semester or session. Problem comes when the students choose elective subjects in the same semester or exam session. "Student Hall Ticket Report" prints all the subjects on every student's Hall Ticket/Roll No. Slip, whereas it should print only those subjects on the student's Hall Ticket/Slip in which the student is enrolled. 
As for as i have searched and tried to solve the issue, i have concluded that this report gets all the subjects offered for exam in an exam session. i have to compare the subjects offered in exam session with the subjects each student had enrolled, if both are same, those should be printed on the Hall Ticket of the student.
Please help me comparing the subject fields in two models; op.exam.session (exam_session) and op.student.course (op_student_course) and in conditionally printing the subjects.
Thanx in advance.
my .py file is as under:

```
import time

from odoo import models, fields, api


class ReportTicket(models.AbstractModel):
   _name = "report.openeducat_exam.report_ticket"
   _description = "Exam Ticket Report"

   def get_date(self, exam_line):
    timestamp = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp
    dt = fields.Datetime
    schedule_start = timestamp(self, dt.from_string(exam_line.start_time))
    schedule_end = timestamp(self, dt.from_string(exam_line.end_time))
    schedule_start = fields.Datetime.to_string(schedule_start)
    schedule_end = fields.Datetime.to_string(schedule_end)

    return schedule_start[11:] + ' To ' + schedule_end[11:]

def get_subject(self, exam_session):
    lst = []
    for exam_line in exam_session['exam_ids']:
        res1 = {
            'subject': exam_line.subject_id.name,
            'date': fields.Datetime.to_string(exam_line.start_time)[:10],
            'time': self.get_date(exam_line),
            'sup_sign': ''
        }
        lst.append(res1)
    return lst

def get_data(self, data):
    final_lst = []
    exam_session = self.env['op.exam.session'].browse(
        data['exam_session_id'][0])
    student_search = self.env['op.student'].search(
        [('course_detail_ids.course_id', '=', exam_session.course_id.id)])
    for student in student_search:
        student_course = self.env['op.student.course'].search(
            [('student_id', '=', student.id),
             ('course_id', '=', exam_session.course_id.id)])
        res = {
            'exam': exam_session.name,
            'exam_code': exam_session.exam_code,
            'course': exam_session.course_id.name,
            'student': student.name,
            'image': student.image_1920,
            'roll_number': student_course.roll_number,
            'line': self.get_subject(exam_session),

        }
        final_lst.append(res)
    return final_lst

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    model = self.env.context.get('active_model')
    docs = self.env[model].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': model,
        'docs': docs,
        'time': time,
        'get_data': self.get_data(data),
    }
    return docargs
```

I am looking for Something like this:

```
        def get_subject(self, exam_session):
        lst = []
        for exam_line in exam_session['exam_ids']:
            res1 = {
                'subject': exam_line.subject_id.name,
                'date':  
fields.Datetime.to_string(exam_line.start_time)[:10],
                'time': self.get_date(exam_line),
                'sup_sign': ''
            }
    If exam_line.subject_id.name == 
course_detail_ids.subject_id.name:

        lst.append(res1)
    return lst
```

But it gives error that object 'course _detail_id' not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that the error comes because inside the function you are not defined the variable course_detail_ids. I think you are trying to compare exam_line.subject_id.name with  exam_session.course_id.name

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anitha Das B, Actually i am new to Odoo and i don't know the exact way to compare two fields from two different models. "|exam_ids" is from module "openeducat_exam", model "exam_session" class "op.exam.session". and i want to compare it with the field "subject_ids" which is defined in module "openeducat_core", model "student", class "op.student.course".